# AWS Quicksight how can i get the untick option to exclude the field from the dataset?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am quite new to AWS Quicksight, from the video tutorials that I have seen, when they are creating a Dataset they have the really handy option to untick the fields to exclude them from the dataset, I dont have that option I have to go into the menu of each one and select exclude which makes this process so slow.

I am just wondering if there is a way to have this feature on?

[image: Quicksight checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

I can only see this option in the documentation like you mention.

My workaround is to use ctrl and select all fields that I want to include or exclude and do them all at ones like that.